# How can a CI controller function receive data from either a form or another function?

Tags: php, codeigniter, post

In my controller, I've created a function to insert a row to the db. It receives input from a form, and passes it on to the model. Here's a simplified version of that controller function:

```
function add_row()
{
$name = $this->input->post('name');
$type = $this->input->post('type');
$newRow = array (
        "name" => $name,
        "type" => $type
    );
$this->places_model->addRow($newRow)
}
```

I've also created another function in the controller that does various other things, and ends up with values of those two fields. Now I want to call the same add_row function, from within the controller, but this time pass the two values generated in my other function.

What's the best way to modify the add_row function so that it will be flexible enough to receive either posted values from a form, or passed values from another function in the same controller?

Comment: why do you need to modify the addRow function to accomplish that?   since its just set to accept an array of the two variables, just have the other function, whose code you didn't post, pass the addRow() function an array as well.

Comment: b/c he's using this function as his post URL.  The request goes directly to this function and not a prior one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function add_row($name = NULL, $type = NULL)
{
    if(isset($_POST["name"]) && $name == NULL)
    {
         $name = $this->input->post('name');
    }

    if(isset($_POST["type"]) && $type == NULL)
    {
         $type= $this->input->post('type');
    }

    $newRow = array (
         "name" => $name,
         "type" => $type
    );
    $this->places_model->addRow($newRow)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function add_row($name ='', $type ='')
{
   if (!empty($this->input->post())
   {
     $name = $this->input->post('name');
     $type = $this->input->post('type');         
    }
     $newRow = array (
             "name" => $name,
             "type" => $type
            );
    $this->places_model->addRow($newRow)
 }
```

Comment: What is their are other post variables set, but not name or type?